# Jest mock function in window

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a function inside the window that retrieves the axios, from there I make the request for my API. I'm trying to mock her and I can't

`window.axios`

In my helper:

`module.exports = () => window.axios`;

In my service:

```
const axios = require('myHelper')

async myFunc() {
    return axios()({
      url: `${myURL}/drafts`,
      method: 'GET',
    });
}
```

In my test file I try to mock and a console, but it comes as undefined.

```
const axios = require('helpers/axios');

jest.mock('helpers/axios');

console.log(axios())
```

I need to `axios().get.mockResolvedValue(myMock)`

Comment: You're invoking `axios()` in your console.log. The mock must be working, otherwise it would error. If you need a different return value, you'll probably want to flesh out your mock using a [manual/custom mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks).